# How to write a Sql query to find distinct values that have never met the following "Where Not(a=x and b=x)"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table called `Attributes`

```
* AttId  * CustomerId  * Class * Code *
| 1      | 1           | 1     | AA   |
| 2      | 1           | 1     | AB   |
| 3      | 1           | 1     | AC   |
| 4      | 1           | 2     | AA   |
| 5      | 1           | 2     | AB   |
| 6      | 1           | 3     | AB   |
| 7      | 2           | 1     | AA   |
| 8      | 2           | 1     | AC   |
| 9      | 2           | 2     | AA   |
| 10     | 3           | 1     | AB   |
| 11     | 3           | 3     | AB   |
| 12     | 4           | 1     | AA   |
| 13     | 4           | 2     | AA   |
| 14     | 4           | 2     | AB   |
| 15     | 4           | 3     | AB   |
```

Where each `Class`, `Code` pairing represents a specific `Attribute`.

I'm trying to write a query that returns all `customers` that are **NOT** linked to the `Attribute` pairing `Class = 1, Code = AB`.

This would return `Customer Id` values 2 and 4.

I started to write `Select Distinct A.CustomerId From Attributes A Where (A.Class = 1 and A.Code = 'AB')` but stopped when I realised I was writing a `SQL` query and there is not an operator available to place before the parentheses to indicate the clause within must **Not** be met.

What am I missing? Or which operator should I be looking at?

**Edit:**

I'm trying to write a query that only returns those `Customers` (ie distinct Customer Id's) that have **NO** link to the `Attribute` pairing `Class = 1, Code = AB`.

This could only be `Customer Id` values 2 and 4 as the table does **Not** contain the rows:

```
* AttId  * CustomerId  * Class * Code *
| x      | 2           | 1     | AB   |
| x      | 4           | 1     | AB   |
```

Changed Title from:

**How to write "Where Not(a=x and b=x)"in Sql Query**

To:

**How to write a Sql query to find distinct values that have never met the following "Where Not(a=x and b=x)"**

As the previous title was a question in it's own right however the detail of the question added an extra dimension which led to confusion.

Comment: `WHERE (A.Class <> 1 AND A.Code <> 'AB')`? or am i missing something?

Comment: try with: `Where (a!=x and b!=x)`

Comment: Both the suggested comments would give me Customer Id's 1, 2, and 3 which is incorrect. I'm trying to find Distinct Customer Id's which have NOT been linked to the pairing Class = 1, Code = AB, which would be Customer Id's 2 and 4 only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId FROM Attributes a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Attributes forbidden 
    WHERE forbidden.CustomerId = a.CustomerId AND forbidden.Class = _forbiddenClassValue_ AND forbidden.Code = _forbiddenCodeValue_
)
```

or with join

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.CustomerId FROM Attributes a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT CustomerId FROM Attributes
    WHERE Class = _forbiddenClassValue_ AND Code = _forbiddenCodeValue_
) havingForbiddenPair ON a.CustomerId = havingForbiddenPair.CustomerId
WHERE havingForbiddenPair.CustomerId IS NULL
```

Yet another way is to use EXCEPT, as per ypercube's answer

Comment: You need to write `SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId ...`

Answer (score 3):

Since no one has posted the simple logical statement, here it is:

```
select . . .
where A.Class <> 1 OR A.Code <> 'AB'
```

The negative of (X and Y) is (not X or not Y).

I see, this is a grouping thing.  For this, you use aggregation and having:

```
select customerId
from Attributes a
group by CustomerId
having sum(case when A.Class = 1 and A.Code = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

I always prefer to solve "is it in a set" type questions using this technique.

Comment: This does answer the question posed when only reading the title, but in the detail of the question there is another dimension which this answer does not meet.

Comment: I'll amend the title to try and avoid further confusion.

Comment: In my case `WHERE NOT EXISTS` would be the better option out of the four suggested solutions but thankyou. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CustomerId 
FROM Attributes

EXCEPT

SELECT CustomerId 
FROM Attributes
WHERE Class = 1
  AND Code = AB ;
```

Comment: In my case `WHERE NOT EXISTS` would be the better option out of the four suggested solutions but thankyou, I wasn't aware of the `Except` and `Intersect` operators. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Distinct A.CustomerId From Attributes A Where not (A.Class = 1 and A.Code = 'AB')
```

Comment: This still gives you customer 1 though

Comment: Is it? **I'm trying to write a query that returns all customers that are NOT linked to the Attribute pairing Class = 1, Code = AB.

This would return Customer Id values 2 and 4.** Doesn't sound like the OP wanted that to be honest, otherwise a simpler query would be `SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID from Attributes`

Comment: @Charleh . . . You are right.  I misunderstood the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.CustomerId From Attributes A Where 
0 = CASE 
         WHEN A.Class = 1 and A.Code = 'AB' THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
END
```

Edit: of course this still gives you cust 1 (doh!), you should probably use pjotrs NOT EXISTS query ideally, serves me right for not looking at the data closely enough :)